# imploding php array and exporting to txt creates duplicate values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

The following script produces the txt file with the required data, but it produces the data twice in the text file.

```
 mysql_connect($hostname_MySQLCon, $username_MySQLCon, "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($database_MySQLCon) or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("
    SELECT sales_flat_order.increment_id, sales_flat_order.gift_message_id, sales_flat_order.status, gift_message.gift_message_id, gift_message.message
    FROM sales_flat_order
    JOIN gift_message ON sales_flat_order.gift_message_id = gift_message.gift_message_id
    WHERE sales_flat_order.gift_message_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY sales_flat_order.increment_id
    /* AND sales_flat_order.status = 'pending' */;") 
 or die(mysql_error());  
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
    $dataRow[] = implode("|", $result);
 } 
$theFile = 'orders-meta.txt';
if (!$handle = fopen($theFile, 'a')) {
    exit;}
if (fwrite($handle, implode("\r\n", $dataRow)) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($theFile)";
exit;}
echo "Success, the file was written.";
fclose($handle);
```

Example output in the txt file:

```
100000001|100000001|1121|1121|pending|pending|1121|gift message|gift message
100000002|100000002|1123|1123|pending|pending|1123|Gift message|Gift message
```

Why would it be producing each value twice? And how can I change it so that output would be:

```
100000001|1121|pending|1121|gift message
100000002|1123|pending|1123|Gift message
```

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: You use context `'a'` in fopen. This means data is appended if the file exist. Use `'w'` to overwrite the file if it exists.

Comment: Yep, as stated somewhere below, you have to use `mysql_fetch_row()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches each result twice, once as an assoc array, once as a numerically indexed array *by default*. That's why you get duplicate rows.

Having said that, please don't use `mysql_*` as it's in the deprecation process, read the read box on the doc pages, and click on the links to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, or the links [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) instead of [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

The default `$result_type` for `mysql_fetch_array` is `MYSQL_BOTH`:

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )

which will produce array like this:

```
array(
    0 => 100000001
    'increment_id' => 100000001,
    1 => 1121,
    'gift_message_id' => 1121,
    2 => 'pending',
    'status' => 'pending',
    3 => 1121,
    4 => 'gift message',
    'message' => 'gift message'
)
```

And why are you storing data in so ineffective way? Why not to do:

```
$theFile = 'orders-meta.txt';
if (!$handle = fopen($theFile, 'a')) {
    exit;
}

while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
    fwrite($handle, implode("|", $result));
    fwrite($handle, "\n\r");
} 

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this explains what's going on - which is that `mysql_fetch_array` returns a mixed key array

Comment: and I've removed my -1 and given you a +1. Good answer

Answer (score 1):

By default, `mysql_fetch_array` returns a mixed array with both numeric and associative keys - so each value is duplicated. Change your fetch line to:

```
mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual:

[mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Then try:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data, MYSQL_NUM ))
```

Comment: Agreed - I should've read the manual first. Thanks for the help.